# Getting Google Site Search to work with my website

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, search

I have a website at. If you try to use the search box it gives a server error. For some reason it is not connecting properly to the Google Site Search and will not bring the results to the page. It at least took me to the search results page before I uploaded it to the server but after it just gives an error. I am new to setting this Google Site Search up on my own and I don't understand what I am missing to get this working.

search.html:

```
<div id="cse" style="width: 100%;">Loading</div>

<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  google.load('search', '1');
 google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
  var customSearchControl = new       google.search.CustomSearchControl('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
  customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
  customSearchControl.draw('cse');
$(".gsc-input").val("<?php echo $_POST['q']; ?>");//insert into  search field requested search text
$(".gsc-search-button").click();//call button click event, show   results
}, true);
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.google.com/cse/style/look/default.css" type="text/css" />
```

Search Box Code from index.html or homepage:

```
 <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="search.html" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="search" value="Search" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Error Code on live site after search and submit:

Server Error

405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.

Console Error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)

New console errors after connecting with method="get" properly:

[image]

Comment: Start by sharing your code with us.

Comment: Add the code and the error. No one can see server code from a URL. The error I saw looked like an IIS error.

Comment: Dont make POST request, Try to make GET request to the google search URL. Or opposite of it. I mean the HTTP verbs are GET, POST, PUT, OPTION etc.. make sure you are using allowed one (Allowed by the destination). Oh in this case use `method="get"`

Comment: I will try the GET option, I am assuming I just replace the POST bit with that?

Comment: It now takes you to the right page after replacing the method="post" with "get" but now I get new error messages which I have updated in the above question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The search will now take you to the search.html page and then allow you to search but it will not add the search query it just prints it inside the google search bar. Something is not setup right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this just by changing my search.html to search.php and then loading it back up onto the server. Makes sense it was something that simple. Code is below, thanks to all who helped me out.

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="search.php" method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="search" value="Search" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

 google.load('jquery', '1');
 google.load('search', '1');
 google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
 var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('your-ID-here');
 customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
customSearchControl.draw('cse');
$(".gsc-input").val("<?php echo $_GET['q']; ?>");//insert into search field requested search text
$(".gsc-search-button").click();//call button click event, show  results
}, true);

</script>
```